# bmv2, libtool: link: 'simple_pre_lag.lo' is not a valid libtool object

Tags: makefile, libtool

While installing bmv2(is the second version of the P4 software switch (aka behavioral model), nicknamed bmv2.). After executing ./configure, 'make' gives me this error: **libtool: link: 'simple_pre_lag.lo' is not a valid libtool object.** libtool is already installed of the newest version.
Anyone has idea what is missing or how to fix this problem?

Comment: what kind of file is simple_pre_lag.lo?

Comment: Its located in bmv2/src/bm_sim. And its blank file. Do you mean this?

Comment: possible problems: A race condition between different processes, the author accidently shipping the file etc. Does it help if you remove the file?

Comment: libtool: link: `simple_pre_lag.lo' is not a valid libtool object
Makefile:446: recipe for target 'libbmsim.la' failed
make[3]: *** [libbmsim.la] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/switch/bmv2/src/bm_sim'
Makefile:528: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving dirctory '/home/switch/bmv2/src'
Makefile:437: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving dir '/home/switch/bmv2'
Makefile:366: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
switch@switch-VirtualBox:~/bmv2$

Comment: okay I give a try by removing the file. thank you

Comment: yes removing this file worked for me, and I completed the installation further. thank you